# Do I have to do anything to brake calipers in order to prep them for refinishing?

Tags: brake-calipers, powder-coating

I have a set of used 2014 Subaru STI calipers that I am considering to have refinished. They're black and have STI logos, but they'll be going on a vehicle that is not an STI which is why I'm considering this.

Currently, they're fairly dirty and do appear to have some oil or brake fluid on them in a few spots. They also still have the original brake pads on them, as well as the other hardware except for the caliper mounting bolts.

Do I need to do anything to these calipers before sending them off to be refinished, most likely powder coated? If so, what?

Answer (score 2):

If someone else is refinishing them for you, you don't HAVE to do anything. Whether or not the person refinishing them for you will charge you extra because they had to do all of the prep work is probably the real thing to consider.

I would at least use some brake parts cleaner to blast the majority of the grime off of them before sending them off. I'd also probably remove the brake pads and brake pad seats (those little metal clips that the brake pad ends sit in) since they won't be refinished during the process. You could also take out the caliper pins, pin boots, and bleeder valve if it can be removed. Anything that saves the refinisher time saves you money!